# Interop Excel reads all Values into 1 Line

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I'm tying to read an Excel-Sheet into an array, but when I read out of the array all values of the whole row are saved in the first column separated by ';'.

How can I save them properly in a 2-dimensional array?

This is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace BB_Entwurf_2
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
        Workbook book = null;
        Worksheet sheet = null;

        string currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        string excelPath;
        excelPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, "MyFile.csv");

        app.Visible = false;
        app.ScreenUpdating = false;
        app.DisplayAlerts = false;

        book = app.Workbooks.Open(excelPath);

        sheet = (Worksheet)book.Worksheets[1];

        int rowCount = sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

        Console.WriteLine(rowCount);

        Range range = sheet.UsedRange;

        object[,] myExcelFileValues = (object[,])range.Value2;

        range = null;

        string test = (Convert.ToString(myExcelFileValues[1,1]));

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        test = (Convert.ToString(myExcelFileValues[2,2]));

        Console.WriteLine(test);

        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheet);
        sheet = null;
        book.Close(false);
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(book);
        book = null;
        app.Quit();
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app);
        app = null;

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Using Excel like this to process CSV files will cause you headaches. Why not use a dedicated CSV parser?

Comment: Sadly where im working right now i cant install anything and can only work with what i have. So ill have to get it to work with excel somehow.

Comment: That makes no sense, you don't install anything to use a CSV parser, it's something you reference directly in the project. If anything it means you need LESS installed on the machine for this to work...

Comment: Excel is already installed, but thanks anyways, just converting the Table to a normal excel file worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll agree with the comments about a CSV parser, but if you're dead set on using Excel, it won't automatically delimit on your semicolon. You'll need to perform a text to columns first. Something like:

```
range.TextToColumns(range[1, 1], XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited, XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, Semicolon: true);
```

If most/all of the values are strings, you could just `split` in your c#.

The aforementioned "CSV parser" solution would just be:

```
excelPath = Path.Combine(currentDir, "MyFile.csv");
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(excelPath);
List<string[]> values = new List<string[]>();
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    values.Add(line.Split(';'));
}
// parse strings into int, double, date, etc.
```

Actually less code and no required installations...

Answer (score 0):

> You can take first blank array and take a loop to get value one by one as follow

```
 string[]  arr = new string[];
Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;                  
  for (int row = 1; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
 {
    arr[row-1] = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 1]).Text;  
 }
```